# On positive real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

let $x > 0$ , $(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N_{\geq 1}}}$ a positive real sequence such that : 
$a^{x}_{1}+...+a^{x}_{n} \geq n t^{x}$ $(*)$ , with $t>0$ . Study the convergence of 
$b_{n}=a_{1}a_{2}..a_{n}$ .
here is what i manage to came up with since I couldn't bring out some kind of upper bound of $a_{n}$ from the relation $(*)$ , I ordered the term of the sequence so that I get a better range of the term $\geq t$  let $\phi : \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1} \to \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$  a bijection  such that $a_{\phi(n)}$ is increasing hence
$a_{1}^{x}+a_{2}^{x}+...+a_{n}^{x}=a^{x}_{\phi(\phi^{-1}(1))}+....+a^{x}_{\phi(\phi^{-1}(n))}\leq na^{x}_{\phi(N)}$ where $N=Max(\phi^{-1}(1),...,\phi^{-1}(n))$
hence $a^{x}_{\phi(N)}\geq t^{x}$  then $a_{\phi(N)} \geq t$ then if $t > 1$ since $\forall m \geq N  a_{\phi(m)}\geq t$  since
$b_{n}=\Pi_{i=1}^{+\infty} a_{i}=\Pi_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_{\phi(k)} \to +\infty$ , here I am stuck , any help or suggestion ? 
Thank's . 
I hope you the best sincerly oty .
another approach  $\Pi a_{i}$ with $\sum a_{i}^{x}$ ?  I tried to  create a relation between the production of $a_{i}$ and the power sum , the idea is the following let $a_{1}^{x}+..+a_{n-1}^{x}=b_{n}a_{n}^{x}$ then it follow that 
$b_{n+1}a_{n+1}^{x}=(b_{n}+1)a_{n}^{x}$ it follow then by induction that 
$a_{n}=a_{1} \Pi_{j=1}^{n-1} (\frac{b_{j}+1}{b_{j+1}})^{\frac{1}{x}}$  , since the relation that we have on the sum of $a_{i}^{x}$ ,$a_{1}\geq t$ 
$b_{n}= (a_{1})^{n}\Pi_{k=2}^{n} (\Pi_{j=1}^{k-1} (\frac{b_{j}+1}{b_{j+1}})^{\frac{1}{x}})$  here i am stuck to estimate the product depending on $b_{j}$